# Showing a pair of vector is the farthest vector pair in certain set

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

Given a set $S$ and a pair of vector $x,y\in S$

I would like to show $x$ and $y$ are the farthest vector pair in the set $S$

I start with showing there doesn't exist a vector $a \in S$ s.t.

$$\|a-y\|>\|x-y\|$$

And then I shown there doesn't exist a vector $b \in S$  s.t.

$$\|x-b\|>\|x-y\|$$

Is it enough?

Comment: I don't think so. Consider the case where four points forms two equilateral triangles, and $x$ and $y$ are two points of the side where two triangles meet.

Comment: @JiminP Sorry I don't really get it. Could you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \{(-3, 0), (3, 0), (0, 4), (0, -4)\}$, $x = (-3, 0)$, and $y = (3, 0)$.

$|| x  - y || = 6$, and since $||(0,4) - y|| = ||(0,-4) - y|| = 5$, there doesn't exist such $a \in S$ that $||a - y|| > ||x - y||$.

Since $||x - (0,4)|| = ||x - (0,-4)|| = 5$, there doesn't exist such $b \in S$ that $||x - b|| > ||x - y||$.

However, $||(0,4) - (0,-4)|| = 8 > ||x - y||$.